# How can I pass a remote file as a command-line argument for a python program?

Tags: python, server, command-line-arguments, remote-access

I need to execute a python program named `score.py`. The execution requires a command-line argument. The command-line argument is the path to the file.

Suppose the file exists in `/home/user/folder_name` then I can execute as

```
python score.py --folder_name /home/user/folder_name
```

But the issue is that the file is present on a remote server. The file occupies gigabytes of memory. So, I thought of not downloading the folder and executing my program.

Is it possible to do it?